# Flutter Firebase Auth Library causes error in Apple M1 Silicon

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, apple-m1

I'm developing flutter application in Apple M1 Silicon.It was working correctly before I added firebase Auth Library. After I added the `firebase_auth: ^0.18.2` dependency in `pubspect.yaml` file I'm getting errors like below , what went wrong here. Thank you

> My logs

```
Prasaths-MacBook-Pro:qwe prasathsivanathan$ flutter run
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 8 in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                           2,826ms
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                            3.6s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    objc[45832]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both ?? (0x204ba8188) and ??
    (0x11b7042b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[45832]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both ?? (0x204ba81d8) and ?? (0x11b704308).
    One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/prasathsivanathan/Desktop/Projects/Flutter/Test3/qwe/ios/Pods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/
    Logger/GULLogger.m:130:20: warning: this old-style function definition is not preceded by a prototype
    [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    void GULResetLogger() {
                       ^
    /Users/prasathsivanathan/Desktop/Projects/Flutter/Test3/qwe/ios/Pods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/
    Logger/GULLogger.m:135:29: warning: this old-style function definition is not preceded by a prototype
    [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    aslclient getGULLoggerClient() {
                                ^
    ]
                              ^
    4 warnings generated.
    /Users/prasathsivanathan/Desktop/Projects/Flutter/Test3/qwe/ios/Pods/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore/Source
    s/FIRLogger.m:61:28: warning: this old-style function definition is not preceded by a prototype
    [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    void FIRLoggerInitializeASL() {
                               ^
    /Users/prasathsivanathan/Desktop/Projects/Flutter/Test3/qwe/ios/Pods/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore/Source
    s/FIRLogger.m:104:20: warning: this old-style function definition is not preceded by a prototype
    [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    void FIRResetLogger() {
                       ^
    2 warnings generated.
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Analyzing workspace
    note: Constructing build description
    note: Build preparation complete
    warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements
    use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in
    target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 8.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error is I'm using Xcode beta 2 version. Still Xcode beta has some
> issues with some library and Xcode Simulator not works.

**or**

> Try to add Developer Certificate into your X-Code